# How do I grep and output certain words from a file until it detects a certain pattern?

Tags: text, awk, grep

In this file:

```
ServerName sdadas.sdsd.sdsa     sdsd.dfdf

fdfd.f.fdfd.d      df.d-f



fgf.gf.fffff
fg.gk
Databases
```

I want to grep the "ServerName" line and all other lines (after "ServerName") including "Databases" (Note: think of this word - Databases - as some random word, it's important that it does not have a dot. And I do not want to output lines after this one)

then after that grep I want to output only words that have a dot inside them ".".

Comment: provide your attempt, sample input and sample output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `awk` will print all word with `.` within them from `ServerName` and stops with first word without `.`

```
awk '/ServerName/ {f=1} f {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/\./) print $i; else if($i!="ServerName") exit}' file
sdadas.sdsd.sdsa
sdsd.dfdf
fdfd.f.fdfd.d
df.d-f
fgf.gf.fffff
fg.gk
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, yes this works great. But I didn't express myself correctly. think of the word "Databases" as just some random word you don't know but you know it doesn't have a dot inside. I need that solution.

Comment: @CzipO Updated answer.

Comment: One more question. How would I run this command on more similar files inside a folder so that the output isall the words with dot from all files?

I tried

```
cat * | awk '/ServerName/ {f=1} f {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/\./) print $i; else if($i!="ServerName") exit}' xargs
``` 
but it doesn't work.

Comment: @CzipO Try the same but without `xargs`. It should work.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work. IT has no error, it just outputs nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a simple one liner with `sed`.

```sh
sed -n '/ServerName/,/^[^.]\+$/ p' file
```

It takes two regexes `ServerName` and `^[^.]\+$` that describe the first and the last line that should be printed.

`ServerName` matches any line that contains this string. You can also use `^ServerName` to match only lines that starts with it.

`^[^.]\+$` matches any non-empty line that has no dot in it.

Comment: This doesn't really work, it prints out the word "Databases and all other lines after.

Comment: Well, it works on GNU sed. What implementation do you use? I suppose it may be more greedy. Does the last line of output contain a dot?

Comment: I'm using Centos7. NO, it basically cats everything in a file after and with the line ^ServerName

Comment: I may be that it uses extended regular expressions by default. Try to remove the backslash before `+`. You may use command `type sed` to see if it is an alias to something.

Comment: None of this works but thank you for trying. I already found the solution. I just need to know how to run this awk on more files.